# Possible to get multiple object from Amazon S3 in single request?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Have a few small files on Amazon-S3 and wondering if it's possible to get 3-4 of them in a single request.

Looked around docs and few SDK's and didn't find anything obvious. I saw they now have "multi-delete", which is nice, but multi get would be great

Anyone know of something like this is possible?

Thanks

Comment: update (4yr later), these may be of interest :
[AWS CLI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/using-s3-commands.html) and [AWS Resource APIs ](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-php-resources)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If you take a look to the lowest level documentation (REST API, for example), the GET operation on objects brings you only one object per request, so whatever you find out in any of AWS SDKs will be a loop over this kind of request.

There are some tools that make it easier to download more than one object. For example, in command-line tools:
`s3cmd get object1 object2 object3 s3://bucket-name`
This call will make sequential requests, meaning the total time won't be reduced, but it indeed makes your task easier to accomplish.

If you prefer doing it in a programmatic way, I suggest using whichever SDK that makes more sense for your platform, and, if it does not contain a batch GET object operation yet, implement your own version according to your own preferences.

Comment: thanks, i just looked at the source of .net sdk, and it's Get-Object in a loop...would be cool of they did provide that though

Comment: @andryuha do you mean they use the REST API get object call in a loop?

Comment: they use an abstraction over it, so basically yes

Comment: Is this still the case? No way to Bulk download from AWS S3 yet? I guess the Batch operations feature also does not support get objects as an operation?

Comment: @Ani https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_Operations.html