# How to get *specific* objects from S3 in a single request using V2 SDK?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am using the [AWS SDK Version 2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v2/developer-guide/welcome.html)

The [DeleteObjects](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_DeleteObjects.html) operation lets you specify up to 1000 keys at a time to delete.

The [ListObjects](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_ListObjects.html) operation is the kind of thing I want - but it appears to only allow specifying a prefix to match.  I can't see how you would use it to list a specific set of objects by their key.

Is there any way to get a set of specific objects from S3 in a single request (or their "head" metadata)?

Comment: What do you mean by "get a set of specific objects"? Do you mean download multiple objects in one API call, or are you wanting to retrieve metadata (eg size, date) of those specific objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I'm reading, this question has been asked before [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11420694/possible-to-get-multiple-object-from-amazon-s3-in-single-request)

Basically says that there isn't a `batch request` implemented yet, so anything you try to do will have to be done coding around that limitation.