# How to get ETag value from a list of objects in an Amazon S3 bucket

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, etag

To get ETag of an object in a ruby code, I can simply use `list_objects_v2` method. But in my use case, I want to get ETags for a list of files.

The problem is there are more than 7000 objects in the bucket. I only want to get the ETag for ~ 1000 of them. One of the ways is to use filename as the `prefix` and query each one of them individually. Probably the last resort.

Is there a way I can pass multiple values for `prefix`? Or any other way in which I can specify to get the ETags for which all objects??

EDIT: While I was looking for a possible way, I ran into https://stackoverflow.com/a/11421066/6200672. I know this is not directly commenting on how the ruby client will work, but according to me, it's gonna use the same API under the hood. (CMIIW)

Comment: Probably listing all files and then filtering only the ones you are interested in isn the way to go. Would be a different story if the bucket had 10M files and you only needed the etags for 20 of them.

Comment: @luk2302 Well this is just one case. I have other similar buckets which have object count of the order 1M. Need to do that there as well.

Comment: No, it is not possible to specify a list of objects for `list_objects()`. An alternative is to use [Amazon S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html), which can provide a daily or weekly CSV file listing all objects. You could then extract the ETags of the desired objects.